# Unable to create Careers profile

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs, profile-page

Hi, I've tried to create my Careers profile a few times, and I'm always getting the following error message:

> Hmm, that email already exists on another account. You will need to log out of your existing account and log back in.

I know that other have run into this problem as well, but I can't seem to find a specific place designated to report this issue, so I apologize if opening a new question is not the preferred way to get this resolved.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I found two accounts for you (one using google, the other yahoo as openID providers) and have gone ahead and merged them. You should be all set now. Try again?

Comment: Thanks.  It looks like it's working now.  I'm a bit confused how that happened.  I thought I had those set as primary and alternate on a single account.  Regardless, I really appreciate the quick help.  Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to hear you're all set.

Comment: @Derek if one of the accounts was more than a few months old, there was a bug that would cause us to not recognize the other as an alternate.  It shouldn't happen in the future, but it's tricky to go back and fix it for all users.

Comment: My account on SO was definitely pretty old.  It was created during the beta.  :)

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I cannot create my Careers profile due the same error message. I think I also fit the criteria described above - my first login was created during the beta and later I linked it to my google account

Comment: @wheelie I can only find one account for you. Can you email me your login info and the email you want to add at careers@stackoverflow.com?

Comment: @Korneel I've just tried again and it's all working now. Thanks for your help

Comment: @wheelie glad to hear!